# Levar dados do QR Code para meus campos

Tags: java, android, qrcode

Estou fazendo a leitura de um QR Code conforme código abaixo:

```
// Botão para abrir câmera e usar o QR Code (Irá abrir a Store para baixar um app nativo)
    btnQR = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnQR);
    btnQR.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
            intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }

        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
            if (requestCode == 0) {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                    String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
                    String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");

                    // Handle successful scan

                } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                    // Handle cancel
                    Log.i("App","Scan unsuccessful");
                }
            }
        }

        private final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
        private CompoundBarcodeView barcodeView;

        private BarcodeCallback callback = new BarcodeCallback() {
            @Override
            public void barcodeResult(BarcodeResult result) {
                if (result.getText() != null) {
                    barcodeView.setStatusText(result.getText());
                }

                String barcode = "35151022986022000105590000400630036591770797|20151013131745|21.26|";
                String[] resp = barcode.split("\\|");

                String cnpj = resp[0].substring(6, 20); // são 14 dígitos, iniciado da posição 7
                String coo = resp[0].substring(30, 35); // supondo que tenham sempre 6 dígitos
                String data = resp[1].substring(0, 5); // 6 primeiros dígitos corresponde a data
                String total = resp[2];

                System.out.println(cnpj);
                System.out.println(coo);
                System.out.println(data);
                System.out.println(total);

                try {
                    Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").parse(data);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                String dataFormatada = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(data);

            }

            @Override
            public void possibleResultPoints(List<ResultPoint> resultPoints) {
            }
        };
    });
```

Preciso que, ao ler o QR Code, volte para min ha aplicação já com os campos preenchidos.

Campos:

```
- CNPJ
- Data
- COO
- Total
```

Comment: Pode postar a string ou parte dela na pergunta, para vermos se tem algum padrao para tratar e separar como você quer.

Comment: **35151022986022000105590000400630036591770797|20151013131745|21.26|** - Tem mais, porém preciso desse começo só

Comment: Adicione na pergunta clicando em [edit] para ela ficar mais completa.

Comment: Aparentemente tem um padrao nessa string, são separados por `|`. Porém nesse trecho que você postou, só tem 3 sequencias separadas, qual a ordem das informações?

Comment: Nessas 3 sequências tem os 4 campos que preciso. o CNPJ começa na casa 7 (22.986.022/0001-05), depois o COO, na casa 31 (003659), depois a data, no segundo bloco (13/10/2015), e por fim, o valor, no último bloco (21.26)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complementando a resposta do @CelsoMarigoJr, você pode usar o método [`split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) para facilitar tratar os dados, porém, há uma correção a se fazer: o método dito não irá [**funcionar corretamente**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808689/why-does-string-split-need-pipe-delimiter-to-be-escaped) sem que o caractere `|` seja escapado, pois o método split espera como um de seus parâmetros uma [**expressão regular**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express%C3%A3o_regular), e o pipe é um caractere especial de ER, conforme [esta resposta no SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10796174).

Então altere:

```
String[] resp = result.getText().split("|");
```

para:

```
String[] resp = result.getText().split("\\|");
```

Fazendo um teste com a string informada por você nos comentários, veja o resultado:

```
String barcode = "35151022986022000105590000400630036591770797|20151013131745|21.26|";        
String[] resp = barcode.split("\\|");
String cnpj = resp[0].substring(6, 20); //são 14 digitos, iniciado da posicao 7
String coo = resp[0].substring(30, 35); // supondo que tenham sempre 6 digitos
String data = resp[1].substring(0, 5); // 6 primeiros digitos sao da data
String total = resp[2];
```

Veja [**aqui**](https://ideone.com/QzVgyG) o código funcionando.

Na data você pode usar a classe [`SimpleFormatDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) para formatar a data e exibi-la de forma mais amigável.

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").parse(data);
String dataFormatada = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(date);
```

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30877/discussion-between-mario-puebla-junior-and-diego-felipe).

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar o [**Split**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm) para separar a String em um array usando um delimitador, no exemplo que você postou, aparenetemente seu delimitador é o "|", portanto faça algo assim:

```
String[] resp = result.getText().split("|");
```

Ai basta percorrer este array e coletar as informações que você precisa.

Me parece que o primeiro campo é uma [***chave de NFe***](http://tdn.totvs.com/pages/releaseview.action;jsessionid=295880F772267BA678E71EEE91907FE5?pageId=54429841), correto!?

Então o CNPJ está na posição 7 com 14 digitos, para pegar com [**Substring**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_substring.htm) use:

```
String CNPJ = resp[0].subsring(7, 14);
```

Comment: obrigado pela resposta. No **resp[0]** ele tá me falando `Array type expected; found: 'java.land.String`. Poderia me ajudar nisso, por favor?

Comment: String[] resp = result.getText().toString().split("|");

Comment: O programa rodou, mas ainda não trouxe os dados para meu campo...creio que tenho que apontar para qual campo tem que ir. Por exemplo, costumo usar muito o `findViewById`, tem algo similar?

Comment: Oque acontece em modo de depuração?

Comment: Obrigado @HiagoSouza pelas edições!

Comment: Disponha @CelsoMarigoJr, não conssegui mudar uma parte, mas você pode onde esta "String CNPJ = resp[0].subsring(7, 14);" na verdade é "String CNPJ = resp[0].substring(7, 14);"... faltou um "T"

Comment: Assim, erro ele não mostra nada. Ele coleta a string do QR Code, mas quando fecha o leitor, meu campo ainda está vazio. Nessa solução do @CelsoMarigoJr eu meio que não informo qual meu campo que deverá ser preenchido, não?

Comment: Qual a necessidade de se passar a string para um vetor pra depois usar substring? Não seria mais pratico pegar direto da string, já que o OP já sabe onde pegar as substrings?

Comment: @MarioPueblaJunior "txtView" essa variavel esta referenciando o textView que você esta querendo colocar a resposta correto? Caso seja tente colocar txtView.setText( CNPJ );

Comment: @HiagoSouza na verdade essas duas linhas de comando eu coloquei só pra testar e ver se o app traria a String gigante que ela trouxe.

Comment: @DiegoFelipe Tem alguma sugestão então no código?

Comment: @MarioPueblaJunior basta você tratar a string diretamente, usando substring para pegar os dados que você me disse em resposta na sua pergunta, como foi sugerido neste código.

Comment: @DiegoFelipe Coloquei assim, vê se tem algo de errado: `EditText cnpj = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cnpj); cnpj.setText(result.getText().substring(7,14);`. Não aconteceu nada, tem alguma coisa errada?

Comment: @HiagoSouza olha a resposta acima

Comment: Vou postar a resposta @MarioPueblaJunior